# Ranger's Focus and Master Hunter

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranger

I'm considering the Guide Archetype. Ranger's Focus seems like a slightly more versatile and powerful combination of Favoured Enemy + Quarry with the downside of being much more limited in uses.

However the problem that concerns me is how this impacts Master Hunter:

> He can, as a standard action, make a single attack against a favored
>   enemy at his full attack bonus. If the attack hits, the target takes
>   damage normally and must make a Fortitude save or die.
>   http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger#TOC-Master-Hunter-Ex-

Since Ranger's Focus replaces Favoured Enemy my hope would be that this feature of Master Hunter would continue to work on a Focused Enemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It doesn't.**

The ability asks for a Favored Enemy. It doesn't give any allowances for replacement abilities, similar abilities, other archetypes, nothing. Your DM may houserule it to work that way - and that's something you'll have to talk over with them - but the black-and-white in the book makes Master Hunter useless unless you've got a Favored Enemy to target.

Comment: Yeah it's too bad. It definitely feels like an oversight, but I agree that without it being specified anywhere it's hard to argue to allow it.

Comment: Such oversights are sadly common. Paizo's standards on that kind of thing are...well, let us just say that they have a design team, but not a development team.